# Calling C Function to Play Audio Within Swift App on Linux

Tags: swift, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm building an app for the Raspberry Pi using Swift. The Pi is connected to a motion sensor and when the sensor is activated I'd like an audio file to play (using a C call to kick off VLC). I've got the motion sensor working and the audio file plays, but when the file is done the C code does not return back to the Swift app unless I press Control-C. Here is the code I'm using:

```
import Glibc


//some SwiftyGPIO inititalization stuff happens here


     while(true){
          if sensor.value == 0 {
             print("No Motion")
          } else {
             print("play music!")
             system("cvlc audiofile.m4a")
          }
          usleep(100000)
     }
```

I'm expecting the main swift app to resume functioning once the c call plays VLC, which it doesn't. Most example apps online for this seem to use OMXPlayer instead of VLC which seems to have been depreciated.I tried looking up alternative methods to kicking off the VLC process.

Comment: `system` is a really limited C API, it always runs synchronously, as you're seeing. Use the Swift [`Process`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process) APIs instead, to run the process in the background while your app resumes

Comment: Thanks! I tried that instead and got it working.